# why it did not echo in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I just follow this from other site https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-socketio, I am still newbie in socket.io with node.js,.I am confuse why it did not echo in the console.can someone help me on this.

Thank you in advance.

app.js

```
var server = require("net").createServer();
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

var handleClient = function (socket) {
    // we've got a client connection
    socket.emit("tweet", {user: "nodesource", text: "Hello, world!"});
};

server.listen(8080);
io.on("connection", handleClient);
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var iosocket = io.connect("http://localhost");


            iosocket.on("tweet", function(tweet) {
                // todo: add the tweet as a DOM node


                console.log("contents:", tweet.text);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean `tweet.user` instead of `.username`?

Comment: Try `io.connect("http://localhost:8080");`

Comment: @Bergi Bingo :-)
And OP Use port number io.connect("http://localhost:8080") or simply use io.connect()

Comment: @Bergi, not working I tried io.connet(); or `io.connect("http://localhost:8080");` still it did not echo, I comment out the tweet.username.

Comment: @jemz: squiroid should be right, try `io.connect("localhost:8080")` or `io.connect("ws://localhost:8080")` - you're not using http

Comment: One more thing, always put your `<script>` in the bottom of the `<body>` since loading is synchronous.

Comment: Does it show any error on console instead ?